# Set attributes (onClick) of a row from another row's attribute in Javascript

Tags: javascript, attributes, onclick, copy

I have a little problem.
I need to copy the attributes of a row, and put them into into a new row I create.

The exact attribute I want to copy is the onClick attribute

I have tried doing this way :

```
newRow.setAttribute("onClick",oldRow.getAttribute("onClick"));
or
newRow.onClick = getAttribute("onClick");
```

When I put an alert to see the attributes of each row, the alert for the new row returns nothing, and the alert for the old row returns something like this :

```
function onClick()
{
    addTable(this,7,Project_1,....  //Over 100 lines of data 
}
```

How can I copy the attributes?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you give us a context to that line...?

Comment: If you actually want to use the same callback for the events of 2 different dom objects, you should rather use addEventListener.

Comment: The thing is I can not access what does the onClick attribute of the old row. The only data I have is the row in itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6gzzp/

The relevant code:

```
document.getElementById("two").onclick = document.getElementById("one").onclick;​
```

Comment: It is weird because it does not work one my computer, but seems to work fine on the demo. I used newRow.onClick = row.onClick; but it does not work

Comment: Actually, Thank you very much it works perfectly!!!!! I wrote onClick instead of onclick.